# Delay When SharePoint 2007 Calls a .Net web service

Tags: sharepoint

We have a SharePoint 2007 site which has custom user controls hosted on SharePoint pages as smart webparts. The user controls call a .net web service on another server. The site was working fine until suddenly all request to the web service are delaying about 20 seconds, and after doing some investigation it turned out that the web service is responding fine, but the requests reside in the SharePoint server for the delay period then it invokes the web service (noticed that using network monitoring tools).

We were checking everything for the past 2 days with no success, so can anyone help please

Comment: Anything in the ULS logs? Any database activities during the waiting period?

Comment: I can only notice many records of "Area: CMS, Category: Publishing, Message: Got List Item Version, but item was null." but not sure if this message is related to my problem. For the database activities, the network monitor tools shows a large amount of communications between SharePoint and SQL during the waiting period.

Comment: That sounds similar to something we've observed in a different scenario (but similar delaying behavior). We had some rather large text columns (in WSS 3.0) that contributed to the delays. But we never quite figured out what caused it. We removed the large columns and things started to improve, but I'm afraid we only delayed the inevitable.

Comment: Have you tried creating a test harness that calls the web services outside of SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, I have created a test web application hosted on the IIS (not as SharePoint site) and it worked fine and had no problems. Have to say that SharePoint pages which do not call a web service are working fine with no problem, the problem is only if there is an event that calls a web service.

Comment: Did you run the test harness actually on your sharepoint server? Could it be something like a DNS resolution delay or other networking problems?

Comment: Yes, it was on sharepoint. I don't think it's a DNS or network thing, since we created a test web application and hosted it on IIS but not as a sharepoint site, and it worked fine.